# Get Checked Box Value for URL Append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two scripts. One that gets the checked boxes value and the other that will append my `<a>` tag. Both work separately but I need the value of 'str' to be placed in my url append script and I can't seem to get it to work.

My get checkbox looks like:

```
<script>
var checked, checkedValues = new Array();
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(e) {

checked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
checkedValues = checked.map(function(i) { return $(this).val() }).get();

$('.aaa').html(checked.length + ' are checked');
if (checked.length) {
    var str = checkedValues.join();
});
</script>
```

My second script to append the url is like:

```
<script>
$('.nextquestion').attr('href', function() {
this.href = this.href + '&answers=+str+';
 });
</script>
```

I am trying to place the value of 'str' in my url. Can someone help?

Comment: Meaby you should do `$('.nextquestion').click(function() {/*compute newComputedUrl*/ window.location = newComputedUrl;});` instead of `$('.nextquestion').attr('href', ...`.

Answer (score 0):

May be str is not accessible inside the function of second script,you might have to make it global variable

```
var str
if (checked.length) {
    str = checkedValues.join();
});

$('.nextquestion').attr('href', function() {
   //here first check if str has value
   this.href = this.href + '&answers=+str+';
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
window.history.replaceState();
```

These are some helper functions I use for this:

```
var addUrlParam = function (param, value) {

    var originalUrlArray = window.location.href.replace(/#/g, "").replace(/!/g, "").split("?");

    var query = originalUrlArray[1] || false;

    var vars = query ? query.split("&").clean("") : [];

    vars.push(param + "=" + value);

    var newQueryString = vars.join("&");

    var newUrl = originalUrlArray[0] + "?" + newQueryString;

    window.history.replaceState(null, null, newUrl);
};

var updateUrlParam = function (paramToUpdate, newValue) {

    var originalUrlArray = window.location.href.replace(/#/g, "").replace(/!/g, "").split("?");

    var query = originalUrlArray[1];

    var vars = query.split("&");

    var newVars = vars.slice();

    var matches = vars.searchFor(paramToUpdate);

    if (matches) {

        for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {

            var pair = vars[matches[i]].split("=");

            if (pair[0] === paramToUpdate) {

                pair[1] = newValue;

                newVars[matches[i]] = pair.join("=");
            }

        }

        var newUrl = originalUrlArray[0] + "?" + newVars.join("&");

        window.history.replaceState(null, null, newUrl);
    } 

};
```